# Failed to Change Directory - Indy 10 - IdFTP

Tags: ftp, delphi-xe5, indy-10

A pasta do ftp é existente, eu verifiquei manualmente e mesmo assim ocorre este erro.

Pasta no ftp:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, segue o código:

```
with IdFtp2 do
  begin
      Host := edtServFTP2.Text;
      Port := StrToInt(edtPorta2.Text);
      ReadTimeout := 0;
      Username := edtUser2.Text;
      Password := Lb3DES1.DecryptString(edtSenha2.Text);
      Passive := true;

      if Connected = false then
        Connect;

      ChangeDir('/RAMONRUAN/'); // a pasta onde vc

            //quer largar os arquivos

    if( ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 ) then//and (erro2 = '')then
    begin
      i := 0;
      while not (i = ListBox1.Items.Count) do
      begin
        try
          Put(ListBox1.Items[i]);
        except
          on e: Exception do ShowMessage('Não colocou o arquvio: '
            +ListBox1.Items[i]+' erro:'+e.Message);
        end;
        inc(i);
      end;
    end;

    IdFTP2.Disconnect;
  end;
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Em qual linha aponta o erro?

Comment: "ChangeDir('/RAMONRUAN/')"; somente ai, e como falei em cima, existe esse diretório.

Comment: Exatamente, da esse erro "Failed to change directoy", há possibilidade de ser o Indy?

Comment: @QMechanic73, eu não utilizo esta função, em que momento eu poderia utilizá-la, ou ela é feita a partir do momento que eu utilizo o `ChangeDir`?

Comment: @QMechanic73, retorna `/var/ftp/MEU_FTP`

Comment: Exatamente. Este caminho. Seria este o problema?

Comment: @RamonRuan Acho que não. Será que você tem permissões de acesso a ele? Veja se esse diretório aparece ao listar: `IdFTP1.List(ListBox1.Items,'',false);`

Comment: Consegui aqui amigo, o problema estava em qual servidor eu estava conectando, daí surgiu pastas do servidor que eu não estava querendo, era apenas um segundo servidor que eu havia conectado antes

Answer (score 2):

Sei que é antigo e resolvido, mas no meu exemplo aqui eu não precisei utilizar as barras /. Somente o nome do diretório dentro do ChangeDir.